# Maximum likelihood estimation in R non-numeric argument error

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, mle

This is my likelihood function for the negative binomial distribution. What am I doing wrong to get this error?

- Error in k + z : non-numeric argument to binary operator

[R code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX16V.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please write your code within the question instead than providing an image. That way, it will be easier to reply. Also, consider having a look at [ask] and [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You have set `z` to a vector, but when you call `optim` you say `z=data`. `data` is a built-in R object (a function), so `k+z` ends up trying to add a function to a number.  I think you wanted `z=z` in your `optim` call ...